# Helm upgrade command fails for no apparent reason

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm-tls

I want to perform a `helm` upgrade on a GKE k8s cluster.

I am executing the following command

```
helm upgrade --force --tls --install --set master.installPlugins=[u'kubernetes:1.21.2', u'workflow-job:2.36', u'workflow-aggregator:2.6', u'credentials-binding:1.20', u'git:4.0.0'] --set master.tag=lts --set agent.tag=3.27-1 -f /org_files/tmp/kerkyra-jenkins/jenkins-values.yaml --namespace jenkins my-jenkins stable/jenkins
```

However it fails with the following name:

> Error: This command needs 2 arguments: release name, chart path

I do pass at the end of the command however both

- release name: `my-jenkins`
- chart path: `stable/jenkins`

Why is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using helm3 it requires the 2 arguments before the flags.

```
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments
Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
```

So this should then work:

```
helm upgrade my-jenkins stable/jenkins --force --tls --install --set master.installPlugins=[u'kubernetes:1.21.2', u'workflow-job:2.36', u'workflow-aggregator:2.6', u'credentials-binding:1.20', u'git:4.0.0'] --set master.tag=lts --set agent.tag=3.27-1 -f /org_files/tmp/kerkyra-jenkins/jenkins-values.yaml --namespace jenkins
```

---

Update: Should be the same for helm 2